# D.R.Y authorization with Gate, laravel 5.2

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, middleware, dry

This is the problem.. I have the next code repeated in different methods and in different controllers.

```
if (Gate::denies('admin-role')) {
   return redirect()->action('HomeController@index')->with('warning','No');
}
```

If someday I decide change the action route or the message I don't want to go through all methods and change it. Is there a way I can put this code in some part and specify the methods where is going to be applied?

I try to do it with middlewares like this:

```
$this->middleware('can:admin-role', ['only' => 'index', 'create']);
```

but I don't know how to custom the redirection.

Use custom middlewares I don't know if its a good idea because then I have to create a middleware for each role(user, admin, superadmin, mixroles, etc).

Comment: In the middleware, instead of returning the $next() response, you can return redirect()->route('my.route')

Answer (score 0):

Create a middleware class and apply that in your routes/route groups, that way you won't have to apply it in individual controllers or their methods.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckRole
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Gate::denies('admin-role')) {
            return redirect()->action('HomeController@index')->with('warning','No');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```